# Ubuntu 22.04 only boots up to a terminal, gui not opening

Tags: boot, apt, uefi, 22.04, gui

I have very recently updated from 20.04 to 22.04.1 LTS on my HP elitebook 840 G8 through `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

The installation looked correct but when it asked me to reboot I could never access the GUI anymore.

The system is apparently on 22.04 as the `lsb release -a` gives me the output I expect (`Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`).

When I start the GUI from a command line `sudo systemctl isolate graphical` it gives me this error: `mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)`.

Additionally when I run the `dmesg` it gives me an error `Could not resolve symbol [\TZ. ETMD]`. I am on a fully updated UEFI BIOS.

I also tried the usual `sudo apt-get clean`, `sudo apt-get update`. The update works but gives me some warnings about jammy not having the resource "stella.cmit" available.

Can someone explain to me what is going on, please? I am completely lost.

Comment: Try the command `startx`.

Comment: Oh yeah I had forgot to mention `startx` returns the `something went wrong` white screen.

Comment: Can you take a picture of the error message with your phone and post it?

Comment: Also try `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: It says it cannot find the package `ubuntu-desktop` and about the error at startx it says `can't find file "en" for symbols include`.

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` helped me...after setting wifi connection from terminal (https://www.techsupportpk.com/2019/05/how-to-enable-wifi-connection-in-rescue-mode-linux.html) and after `sudo apt upgrade` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` reported that all packages have been updated/installed.

Comment: sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue; just solved it.

The reason I couldn't do `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` that my software repository list (`/etc/apt/sources.list`) had been messed up. Luckily I was able to use `nano` to edit the `sources.list` file via command line, and after that, `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` worked like a charm!

Comment: How to use 'nano' to edit the sources.list? I'm having the same issue as you.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue when I updated my system with an update that looked weird (don't really know how to explain it otherwise). So first I ran the command `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`  just to make sure that the upgrade was done properly. After that I reinstalled ubuntu-desktop with the command `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and that solved the problem (It also installed some games like cards and mahjong).

Comment: This worked for me.  I successfully upgraded to 22.04.3 and then installed VPN, etc. Next reboot X would not start. Arrg!  But a reinstall of ubuntu-desktop recovered.  I see some bootup errors but they seem to be minor.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug in 22.04. I had the same problem after upgrading from 21.04 to 22.04. I couldn't fix it and restored my 21.04 image again.

After a lot of Google research I found this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1981622) entry. Unfortunately, this only helps to a limited extent when the system no longer boots.

In several places I read, that manual entries of hdd partitions in fstab could be the source of the problem. In my case that could be true also. So far, however, I could not bring myself to test the upgrade again ;-)

Comment: I ended up going for a 22.04 fresh install instead! It took some time to reinstall all packages but the experience was way smoother than the upgrade. Luckily I also had all the critical data backed up (and the less critical one was also recoverable from the terminal anyway).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

(a) Check the setting

```
sudo systemctl get-default
```

(b) Reset if it does not report 'graphical.target'

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical
```

Then reboot and it should boot into the UI again.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 23.04.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. And the same error :

```
error: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
```

when trying to access GUI from command line.
Tried to reinstall ubuntu desktop via:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

but reinstall attempt failed and logged something about missing pipewire package in latest version. I installed missing package following steps described here:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-pipewire-on-ubuntu-linux

Then I tried to reinstall desktop again and this time it worked and swiched to desktop straight away, so, worked like a charm. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo reboot now
```

However, GUI was still unresponsive, so I reinstalled the desktop with:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue and this worked for me:

```
$ sudo systemctl isolate graphical
```

What this line will do is that it will start the gui manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use startx command, if it doesn't work use: sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo reboot now

Comment: This is nearly a copy of the answer above by Anjali.