# Upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 failed

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

I am fighting to upgrade my Ubuntu and I am dealing with troubles. I tried to do it with `sudo do-release-upgrade` and also from the Software Updater. I tried out a lot of things (here on StackExchange, ChatGPT) but I am still getting the following screen.

[image]

I believe I removed all PPAs and third party repositories. Maybe I missed something. I am really not sure.

[image]

If I need to provide more info to fix the issue please let me know.

Comment: The error message "Could not calculate the upgrade" suggests a version conflict. "*I removed all ppa and third party repositories*" suggests that you did not uninstall the packages provided by those non-Ubuntu sources. It's the packages that cause the version conflict(s).

Comment: And how to find these packages? And be sure I delete all of them?

Comment: look at this question and answers https://askubuntu.com/questions/360293/could-not-calculate-the-upgrade-what-happened

Comment: Hey @TalaatEtman thank you a lot for your suggestion! I needed to remove and fix broken packages. Mostly remove them one by one. 
But it was worth it because the upgrade succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I see some [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360293/could-not-calculate-the-upgrade-what-happened) tell us the upgrade may be continue after remove 1-3  broken packages.
so if you face that again you can tray upgrade after every one package removing

Comment: @Martin happy news, sorry I Can’t make comment for you in the question

Comment: After the upgrade and restart of the system, there is an issue with GUI. 
So basically only thing that shows up is I think so called "ppy".
What I needed to do is to reinstall ubuntu desktop, as is suggested here
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423340/ubuntu-22-04-only-boots-up-to-a-terminal-gui-not-opening
Now is everything perfect! I would love to give you upvote but unfortunatelly my points are lower than 15 :(

Comment: @Martin don’t wary we just tray to help