# Ubuntu 23.04 won't boot to GUI

Tags: boot, 23.04

I've been using it for a couple months, but after the last reboot it just boots to the flashing cursor screen.  I can log into cli, and have run update-grub, but it still doesn't boot.

Comment: You've provided few specific details. Common causes for such failures are changes made in the last session prior to this change; but you've not provided any clues as to what user(s) did, what packages were installed etc. As you can boot into CLI you should have access to logs (*terminal history will show package installs; or you can peruse apt logs if a GUI or front-end tool was used*).

Comment: Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1469328); it worked for me.